# Prevent fork from adding --inspect-brk

Tags: node.js

My application calls `child_process.fork` during execution. I would like to use `--inspect-brk` to debug the tests, but I do not care about the forked process. I actually specifically need the `forked` process to *not* inherit the `--inspect-brk` flag. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [child process docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), for `child_process.fork`:

> execArgv  List of string arguments passed to the executable.
>   Default: process.execArgv

So, the forked process inherits the main process arguments passed. With that in mind, you should override `execArgv`:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var foo = cp.fork('./foo.js', { execArgv: [] });
```

Comment: :( not as easy as I'd hoped it would be.

Comment: Well, I was hoping there was a global option I could set, but since this is just for some tests I think it's fine to throw in logic to remove it.

Comment: OOOH, I get it. since `fork` is only for forking a new node process (in general) the execArgv for the original node command is copied over. The args for `fork` are passed directly to `foo.js`. OK, this is great! Thanks!